# Htaccess for Wordpess set on single subdomain

Tags: htaccess, subdomains, domain, hosting

**Situation**

- I have standard hosting in OVH (not VPS) and I'm able to set many websites on it in a different subdirectories,
- I would like to install 2 instances of Wordpress - first in directory `/A` and secend in directory `/B`
- I would like "A" to use `domain.com` and "B" to use `subdomain.domain.com`

**Question**

- In that case need I use standard `.htaccess` configuration for Wordpress on a single domain in each Wordpress directory or have I to use special configuration for subdomain in each Wordpress directory ?

*Domain*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*SubDomain*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- or maybe should I use subdirectory version of `.httaccess` ?

*SubFolder*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is: use the same standard `.htaccess` configuration for Wordpress on a single domain in each Wordpress directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Along with it, add a small CODE to make sure users are redirected to the correct domain in case they reach to that subdirectory using another domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://domain.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

After that, your `.htaccess` for `domain.com` will be like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://domain.com/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and for `subdomain.domain.com`, it'll be like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://subdomain.domain.com/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## Reasons:

1. Using standard CODE is recommended because it's easier to maintain & debug, as it's same everywhere.
2. The extra two line are recommended mainly for `SEO`. Without them, one of your domain may be accessible using another domain. That may raise some duplicate content question.

Comment: Sounds reasonable :)